# display pdf file from assets folder by filename in Angular 2

Tags: angular, pdf

My angular 2 app is required to find the pdf file in the assets folder based on the file_name coming from the rest api and display by opening in a new tab. Could you please tell me how to proceed?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to produce a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); aside from this, be sure to show us what you've tried; what the issue is, what behavior is expected, etc.

Comment: My apologies, I meant I cant figure out how to achieve that and display the pdf. I am new to stackoverflow and angular2